# Filtered query on a nested object in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Document:

```
{
  "issue_id": 1100,
  "text_content": [
    {
      "page": 1,
      "content": "First Page"
    },
    {
      "page": 2,
      "content": "Second TOC"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above document is indexed in `issues` index with a type `issue_text`.
Below is the mapping on the type.

Mapping:

```
{
  "issues": {
    "mappings": {
      "issue_text": {
        "properties": {
          "issue_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "text_contents": {
            "type": "nested",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "properties": {
              "content": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "page": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/issues/issue_text/_search" -d'{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "issue_id": 1109
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "text_contents",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "text_contents.content": "toc"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I am getting an error. 
nested: QueryParsingException[[issues] [nested] nested object under path [text_contents] is not of nested type].

I am trying to fetch text_contents object which match the word "toc" for an document with the given issue_id(1109). In short - trying to filter and find a certain document and then perform a full text search on a nested object in that document.

Comment: works on my machine with provided query/mapping/document. Only change I had to do was update of  `text_content` document attribute to `text_contents` to match the mapping.